# complex blending in html5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need to recreate and animate a complex illustration, which has been created in illustrator, as a web page.
The illustration consists of multiple shapes ( circles, squares waves ) which use different blend modes. so one circle might use "difference" and another one "multiply" etc.

Is it possible to have multiple different blend-modes on different graphics within the same canvas-element like I would in Illustrator / Photoshop etc.?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there are relatively few shapes then use SVG. If you have hundreds of shapes then use Canvas. If you must support IE then you must use SVG because IE's canvas does not support blending.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, html5 can be used to draw shapes with individual blending applied.**

One warning is that you can only do one blend at a time so if one of your shapes requires multiple blends then you must do each blend sequentially.

If your shapes will overlap each other on the canvas then you can compose each blended shape on a second "staging canvas". The staging canvas is in-memory and not visible.

Also, blends are new in MS-Edge so blends are not available in MS's IE line of browsers.

**Here's starting example code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var shape1=stageShape('multiply','red','blue');
var shape2=stageShape('difference','red','blue');

ctx.drawImage(shape1,50,50);
ctx.drawImage(shape2,75,30);

function stageShape(blendMode,color1,color2){
  var c=document.createElement("canvas");
  var cctx=c.getContext("2d");
  c.width=80;
  c.height=80;
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.arc(30,30,30,0,Math.PI*2);
  cctx.fillStyle=color1;
  cctx.fill();
  cctx.globalCompositeOperation=blendMode;
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.arc(50,50,30,0,Math.PI*2);
  cctx.fillStyle=color2;
  cctx.fill();
  return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you.
well in my case i have for example a red circle with blend mode "multiply" over a blue circle with blend mode "difference" over a green circle with blend mode "color dodge" over the background color.
Is the "staging canvas" needed to abstract this?

Comment: Yep, a staging canvas (or two, or more) will be needed to do sequential blends. But the good news is that blending is done on the GPU (when available) so it is very fast.

Comment: Thanks again. 
That gives hope, albeit it looks quite elaborate ... :)

Would you have more info on the "staging canvas" concept?
Trying to find more examples now in the Rest of the interwebs.

Comment: @zantafio A staging canvas is simply a work-canvas used to build one blend in a series of blends.  The example uses one staging canvas to separate the 2 blend modes. I've edited my answer to overlap the positions of the each blend to show what could not easily be achieved without the second staging canvas. For more complex blends you might even need to use more than one staging canvas. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sure helps